# Download image from Firebase Storage into local storage [Web]

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have gotten the downloadable URL from Firebase Storage and I would like to automatically download the image to my local computer  when I click on the button.

Here is what I did:

```
<a href="<URL> download>
   <button>Download</button>
</a>
```

I have configured the CORS (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration).

However when I click on it, it open the image in new tab instead of downloading it.

I also got this error from the opened tab:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}
```

I have also tried with this (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) but when I click on it, nothing is happening.

Anyone can help with that? :(